# How can I click in link but without "a href" [Selenium + Python]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I don't know how can I click on "Utwórz konto" on https://www.morele.net/login.

I tried:

```
link_registration = driver.find_element_by_class_name("//li[@class = 'el-login-nav register']")
link_registration.click()
```

but I get error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given
>   css selector expression ".//li[@class = 'el-login-nav register']" is
>   invalid: InvalidSelectorError: './/li[@class = 'el-login-nav
>   register']' is not a valid selector: ".//li[@class = 'el-login-nav
>   register']"

Comment: you are passing an xpath but using `find_element_by_class_name`. you could just pass `el-logic-nav register`.

Answer (score 0):

*You are trying to pass an XPath expression to the "by class name" locator* - no wonder it fails.

I would use a CSS selector instead:

```
register = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".autorization-form .register")
register.click()
```

`.autorization-form .register` would match an element having a `register` class somewhere (at any depth level) inside an element having an `autorization-form` class. Space here means *parent-child relationship* - but the child can be at any level inside the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you used the `find_element_by_class_name()` command but passed in an xpath. You need to either use `find_elements_by_xpath()` or a different locator function. Either of these should work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class = 'el-login-nav register']");
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.register")
```

Comment: Hm, I have here error: "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element is not visible"